# What is the meaning of "blob of glup"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, vocabulary

This term was used in this way, for the first time: “The oyster is a blob of glup, but a woman is a woman.” ― James Thurber, The 13 Clocks . I also saw some articles using this phrase, but I just don't get it.

Comment: I'd normally spell it [***gloop***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/71934288?redirectedFrom=gloop#eid) - defined by the full OED in that link as *A glutinous or viscous substance; a lump or blob of this type of substance*. Note that the OED doesn't actually list the spelling ***glup***, although that seems to be the more common version in Google Books. It's probably a mash-up of ***slop*** and ***goo*** (influenced by ***glug / gulp***, in Thurber's context).

Comment: I feel my mind expanding. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say Thurber's "humorous aphorism" here is a complete one-off, but the basic construction is idiomatically well established. And one particularly well-known version that comes to mind as a kind of "opposite" is Rudyard Kipling's 1855 offering: *A **woman** is only a woman, but a good cigar is a **smoke***. Which Thurber would have been perfectly familiar with, so we could say he's "riffing" off that "original".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Glup' seems to be a (possibly) Thurber-invented term meaning roughly 'slimy, jelly-like material', similar to [guck](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/guck).

[image]

I believe the remark is intended to be humorous (using [bathos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathos)), contrasting a slimy food, offering a small amount of transitory pleasure to the small number of people who like oysters, with the much more fulfilling possibilities offered by interaction with a woman. Presumably the remark was written to be understood from a traditional sexist male viewpoint. To be contasted with the similar rather misogynistic remark by Groucho Marx, borrowed from Rudyard Kipling: 'a woman is just a woman, but a good cigar is a smoke'.

Comment: You saved my mind. I was getting crazy about it! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, Groucho Marx was just repeating [Rudyard Kipling's](https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/betrothed.html) original aphorism